# Cómo actualizo un AlertDialog en flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

cómo estamos ?
tengo un inconveniente con una función en flutter que, por un lado quiero que el usuario no pueda tocar otro lado de la pantalla hasta que finalice dicha función y al mismo tiempo, mostrar el progreso de lo que va procesando la función. En sí es simple, lo que hace es llamar a un puerto tcp para generar un portknocker:

```dart
void doToken(context, String _host, List<dynamic> _puertos) async {
  Socket? socket;
  int _puerto = 0;
  int _counter = 1;

 //llama a cada puerto
  for (_puerto in _puertos) {
    try {
      socket = await Socket.connect(
        _host,
        _puerto,
        timeout: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    print(_counter);
    _counter++;
    socket?.destroy();
//espera entre knocks
    sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
}
```

Si coloco un showdialog() dentro del for, me genera un nuevo mensaje cada vez que itera. Lo que quiero es que la alerta se vaya actualizando con _counter y al final, que desaparezca.

Gracias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías mover tu lógica al AlertDialog y actualizarlo mediante un StatefulBuilder:

Este ejemplo inicia un contador de 10 a 0 cuando presionas Ejecutar y va mostrando la información en el content de la alerta.

```
  mostrarAlerta() {
    int mensaje = 10;
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter cambiarEstado) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(mensaje.toString()),
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(19, 8, 128, 2.0),
                    ),
                    child: Text('Ejecutar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      for (int x = mensaje; x > 0; x--) {
                        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
                          cambiarEstado(() {
                            mensaje -= 1;
                          });
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```